# Strip-Ansi using require() instead of import, generating exception

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

I have an angular 13 project and when I try to serve the project I get this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred: require() of ES Module
> C:\Users\username\Documents\project\builds\Production2\tbsis\UI\node_modules\ansi-regex\index.js
> from
> C:\Users\username\Documents\project\builds\Production2\tbsis\UI\node_modules\strip-ansi\index.js
> not supported.

This is the content of C:\Users\username\Documents\project\builds\Production2\tbsis\UI\node_modules\strip-ansi\index.js:

```
'use strict';
const ansiRegex = require('ansi-regex');

module.exports = string => typeof string === 'string' ? string.replace(ansiRegex(), '') : string;
```

It seems this require statement is causing the error.

How can I get around this?

I tried changing it to

```
import ansiRegex from 'ansi-regex';
```

But that gave this error when trying to serve

> An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot use import statement outside a
> module See
> "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-Z69dHd\angular-errors.log" for
> further details.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "startl": "ng serve --base-href \"\\\"",
    "build": "ng build ",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "postinstall": "ngcc",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^13.1.4",
    "@angular/animations": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^13.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.3.1",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^22.1.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "^22.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "8.0.0",
    "node-gyp": "^7.1.2",
    "npm": "^8.3.1",
    "rxjs": "7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.9.1",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "12.12.6",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "grunt": "^1.4.1",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.4.3",
    "grunt-war": "^0.5.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.9.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^5.0.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "postcss": "8.2.13",
    "ansi-regex": "6.0.1",
    "node-forge": "1.3.1",
    "qs" : "6.10.3",
    "@angular/core" : "^13.1.2"
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you just remove ansi-regex from overrides?  It's likely strip-ansi is an older version looking for an older version of ansi-regex.  Remove ansi-regex from overrides.  Delete package.lock.  Reinstall everything.  Look at package.log and see what's importing strip-ansi.  See if you can upgrade that to use a newer version.

Comment: I deleted package-lock.json, removed ansi-regex from overrides, and removed node_modules and ran the install again. Got the same error. 6.0.1 is the latest version so the override should be overriding any older dependencies. What do you think?

Comment: Yeah, but whoever is using strip-ansi is probably importing an older version.  So I would update that.

Comment: Also seems super weird that you need npm and node-gyp as dependencies in your project.  It might make sense to remove what you don't need.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I have a similar issue.

Comment: never mind, just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76753440/react-app-build-fails-with-err-require-esm which has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The package is erroring as it's trying to import a `Common JS` source so you need to implement it yourself.

First import `ansi-regex` (the package `strip-ansi` is trying to import and use under the hood) inside your ESM with `import`:

```js
const ansiRegex = (await import("ansi-regex")).default;
```

then you can use it this way:

```js
const regex = ansiRegex();
const stringWithoutAnsi = tartgetString.replace(regex, "");
```